# Php Mysql sum total with select all rows returned

Tags: php, mysql

How can i query and return all the rows but with "SUM" added to my query?

Here is my sample query:

```
select SUM(amount) as total, user_id, username, from table where user_cat = '1';
```

if I remove `SUM`, I get the correct number of rows returned, but when I add `SUM`, the row result is decreased.

Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: So you want the results of when you query with SUM and without SUM in one query? Your best off doing two separate queries or doing the math in the application layer (as opposed to the database query if you need to limit your number of queries for some reason)

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions (like SUM) in your queries which return rows more than 1. You can make query and than count results with PHP.

Comment: Do you want to count rows or do math? If you want to count, then use `COUNT` and not `SUM`

Comment: thank you guys for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have noticed it's impossible to make the query in the way you tried as SUM() aggregates the other rows and only one row is displayed. One way to solve this is to separate SUM() in a subquery as described below:

```
select n.total, 
  user_id, 
  username  
  from table, 
  (select SUM(amount) as total 
    from table 
    where user_cat = '1') n 
  where user_cat = '1';
```

I prefer to make this in two separate queries. Now you'll have to deal with the first column and make it invisible. If you use two queries you'll have to deal with the second query. The choice is yours.

Comment: Please improve your answer with some additional explanations

Comment: @ABFORCE Of course, but there was a match on the tv and I didn't want to miss it...